# Как на вход подать файл в виде текста на 500 строк из заголовков

Tags: python

Это многослойный перцептрон на глубоком обучении.
https://linghub.ru/static/Taiga/?C=S;O=D
Я хочу добавить все данные на вход, чтобы на выходе получилась модель, которая может общаться с человеком через телегу.

```
import tensorflow as tf

filename = r'Arzamas\text'

with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    content = file.readlines()

X_train = file.readable()
y_train = 3

text = ''.join(content[:500])

num = 100

# Определение архитектуры перцептрона
input_size = num
output_size = num
hidden_layers = 12
hidden_units = num

# Создание модели перцептрона
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_units, input_shape=(input_size,), activation='relu'))  # Входной слой

# Добавление скрытых слоев
for _ in range(hidden_layers):
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_units, activation='relu'))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(output_size, activation='softmax'))  # Выходной слой

# Компиляция модели
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Вывод структуры модели
model.summary()

# Обратное распространение ошибки
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=32)

# Оценка модели на тестовых данных
loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(text)
print(f"Точность модели: {accuracy}")
```